# mysqli prepared statement woes

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to implement my first prepared statement using mysqli.

At the moment I have this:

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli('example.com', 'user', 'password', 'database');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();}

$first = $_GET['firstname'];
$last = $_GET['surname'];
$dob = $_GET['dob'];
$address = $_GET['homeaddress'];
$college = $_GET['college'];
$emergname = $_GET['emergencyname'];
$emergnumber = $_GET['emergencynumber'];
$condition = $_GET['condition'];
$conditiondetails = $_GET['conditiondetails'];
$medication = $_GET['medication'];
$medicationdetails = $_GET['medicationdetails'];

if($stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO medical ('forename', 'surname', 'dob', 'address', 'college', 'emergency_name', 'emergency_number', 'condition', 'condition_details', 'medication', 'medication_details') VALUES (:forename, :surname, :dob, :address, :college, :emergencyname, :emergencynumber, :condition, :conditiondetails, :medication, :medicationdetails)")){

$stmt->bind_param(':forename', $first);
$stmt->bind_param(':surname', $last);
$stmt->bind_param(':dob', $dob);
$stmt->bind_param(':address', $address);
$stmt->bind_param(':college', $college);
$stmt->bind_param(':emergencyname', $emergname);
$stmt->bind_param(':emergencynumber', $emergnumber);
$stmt->bind_param(':condition', $condition);
$stmt->bind_param(':conditiondetails', $conditiondetails);
$stmt->bind_param(':medication', $medication);
$stmt->bind_param(':medicationdetails', $medicationdetails);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();} ?>
```

I have previously tried a variance using:

```
<?php
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO medical ('forename', 'surname', 'dob', 'address', 'college', 'emergency_name', 'emergency_number', 'condition', 'condition_details', 'medication', 'medication_details') VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")

$stmt->bind_param('sssssssssss', $first...);
?>
```

In both instances I get an error message that the $stmt variable doesn't exist.

Any suggestions as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting exactly in which line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column names should be escaped with backticks, not single-quotes. Also, you can't use named parameter bindings.

Try

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO medical (`forename`, `surname`, `dob`, `address`, `college`, `emergency_name`, `emergency_number`, `condition`, `condition_details`, `medication`, `medication_details`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")

if (!$stmt)
{
  echo $con->error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using this SQL syntax instead:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO medical VALUES (:forename, :surname, :dob, :address, :college, :emergencyname, :emergencynumber, :condition, :conditiondetails, :medication, :medicationdetails)");

$stmt->bind_param(':forename', $first);
$stmt->bind_param(':surname', $last);
$stmt->bind_param(':dob', $dob);
$stmt->bind_param(':address', $address);
$stmt->bind_param(':college', $college);
$stmt->bind_param(':emergencyname', $emergname);
$stmt->bind_param(':emergencynumber', $emergnumber);
$stmt->bind_param(':condition', $condition);
$stmt->bind_param(':conditiondetails', $conditiondetails);
$stmt->bind_param(':medication', $medication);
$stmt->bind_param(':medicationdetails', $medicationdetails);
$stmt->execute();
```

Or try:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO medical VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$stmt->bind_param('sssssssssss', $first, $second, $third, $fourth, $fifth, $sixth, $seventh, $eighth, $ninth, $tenth, $eleventh);
```

Meaning, without no Use-Fields declaration in your INSERT statement.